# Computer is far away from my desk: Is it possible to wireless connect a display monitor to it? How?

Tags: monitors, bluetooth

I have a big desktop that needs to stay in a room next door to mine. Not that far but of course I cannot run a monitor cable from the desktop to my desk. So my question is simple:

Is there any technology that allows me to wireless connect my computer monitor to my away desktop? Something link bluetooth.

I know there are bluetooth keyboard and mouse. The other problem is: I already have a monitor so it would have to be some kind of adapter to stream the display signal from my away desktop to my desk monitor.

Does that exist?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [KVM over IP](http://www.aten.com/global/en/products/kvm/kvm-over-ip-switches/?f26%5B%5D=1) for that purpose. You just need to connect your PC and your desk with ethernet cable. It's not so cheap and has some limitations for screen resolution, but maybe it can solve your problem. You can find examples of this devices [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).

Here is another wireless option [Wireless Extender for HDMI](http://Wireless%20Extender%20for%20HDMI).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is [WiGig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Gigabit_Alliance). You need a compatible wireless adapter and a dock. There are some wireless adapters for laptops that support it from Intel and a few docks from Lenovo, Dell, etc. If your desktop has a compatible port for an adapter (M.2 with PCIe) then you're good to go.